# Why can we find forces like this using energy methods?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, energy-conservation

Often to calculate forces in complex situations (usually involving complicated mathematics), I have seen various people employ energy methods. The answer comes out correct, but I can't understand why the reasoning is correct. For instance, consider the problem of finding the excess pressure in a spherical drop of water of radius $R$.

Assume that the water drop expands from $R$ to $R+dR$. **The work done by the excess pressure must be equal to the change in surface energy**. And so,

$$(4\pi R^2 dR )\Delta p = (8 \pi R dR) T$$

where $T$ is the surface tension of water. Solving for $\Delta p$ yields the well-known relation

$$\Delta p = \frac{2T}{R}$$

I have two problems with this,

- How can we make the assumption I have highlighted in bold? Furthermore, why can assume the drop expands anyway? The drop is in stable equilibrium and has no reason to change its configuration.
- Why is this only valid for a small expansion? If we replace $dR$ by $\Delta R$ in the above derivation and then use the formulas for change in volume and surface area($\frac{4\pi[(R+\Delta R)^3-R^3]}{3}$ instead of $4\pi R^2\Delta R$), we will get a different result.

While answering please keep in mind that it is not only this particular example that I have a problem with but this technique in general. I have illustrated just one use of the technique to make my problem clear. I would appreciate it if you could explain when and why we can apply this technique.

Comment: It is assuming a reversible expansion, precisely because you don't want to disturb the system. By analyzing how the system reacts to infinitesimal changes you can get information about the current state. The reason why you equate those two terms is because that's where all the energy is going, excess pressure is invested in creating more surface until equilibrium is reached again.

Answer (score 2):

This technique is called "[virtual work](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_work)".

Here is a simple example. Suppose you have a see-saw with uneven masses

[image]
[source](http://www.chegg.com/homework-help/questions-and-answers/two-people-different-masses-sit-seesaw-m1-mass-person-1-94-kg-m2-41-kg-d1-08-m-d2-12-m-mas-q3876475)

The seesaw will be balanced when the torques add to zero. Let's take the torque from mass $M_1$ and call it $\tau_1$ and likewise for the other side. The torque is a function of $\theta$, the angle the see-saw makes with the horizontal. We will balance the see-saw as some particular $\theta_0$. That means

$$\tau_1(\theta_0) + \tau_2(\theta_0) = 0$$

If you were to grab the see-saw with your hand and forcibly rotate it through an interval of angles $(\theta_0 , \theta_1)$, the torques would do work on the see-saw given by

$$W = \int_{\theta_0}^{\theta_1} \left(\tau_1(\theta) + \tau_2(\theta)\right) \mathrm{d}\theta$$

In the limit $\theta_1 \to \theta_0$, the integrand does not change over the interval, so we have

$$\mathrm{d}W = \left(\tau_1(\theta_0) + \tau_2(\theta_0)\right)\mathrm{d}\theta$$

but because the torques sum to zero, that gives

$$\mathrm{d}W = 0$$

We see that in the limit of very small displacements, the energy of the system does not change when the system is in equilibrium.

In the principal of virtual work, we take that as a starting point. We assume the equilibrium is where the energy is stationary and derive the law for the forces.

In this case, if we make a small displacement $\mathrm{d}\theta$ from the point $\mathrm{\theta}_0$, mass $M_1$ moves down by $d_1 \cos\theta \mathrm{d}\theta$ and so the work done on it is the change in its energy, which is the change in (mass times gravity times height), which is $-M_1 g d_1 \cos\theta \mathrm{d}\theta$. The work done by the torque $\tau_1$ on the see-saw is $M_1 g d_1 \cos\theta \mathrm{d}\theta$. The work done by torque $\tau_2$ on the see-saw is $-M_2 g d_2 \cos\theta \mathrm{d}\theta$. We know that the total work done on the board is zero in equilibrium for small displacements, so

$$M_1 g d_1 \cos \theta \mathrm{d}\theta - M_2 g d_2 \cos\theta \mathrm{d}\theta = 0$$

in equilibrium, or

$$ \tau_1(\theta) + \tau_2(\theta) = 0$$

which recovers what we already knew. We can also simplify the expression to

$$M_1 d_1 = M_2 d_2$$

Note that we do not claim that the see-saw actually does make a displacement. We're just calculating what the change in energy would be if there were a displacement and setting that equal to zero. This is just another way of saying that equilibrium states have minimum energy.

That is the general idea. We know that in equilibrium, the forces (or generalized forces; in this example torques) sum to zero. Therefore the work done under small displacements is zero. Therefore the energy is minimized. Therefore, we can start our analysis by looking at energy if we so desire. You will need to use the appropriate equilibrium condition depending on your situation, so for a soap bubble with air inside you need to worry about minimizing the free energy, not the internal energy.

It will be useful to work out how this applies to a bubble as in your question.

Comment: I don't see how this applies to energy the function of energy at maximum and minimum points. The integral of any function as the upper and lower limit approach each other approaches zero. What's special here?

Comment: do you understand the the difference between 1st order infinitesimals vs.2nd order infinitesimals?

Comment: Gerard, I am describing the asymptotic behavior of the integral to first order in $\mathrm{d} \theta \equiv \theta_1 - \theta_0$

Answer (score 1):

Because initially system is in equilibrium and the energy is at local minimum (or maximum). So the first derivative of energy is equal to zero

$$
    dE(\rm{variables}) = 0
$$

You can rewrite first condition as if there is a sum of negative and positive term and this sum is equal to zero. This is also why you should use infinitesimal changes in variables.